# Adding a Photo to Facebook Album does not modify Album modified time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

Is it a bug or a valid feature on Facebook, when a Photo is uploaded to an existing Album it does not modify Album's modified date? What does modified_major field on Album do?

Answer (score 0):

Editing the album's metadata updates the modified time

Adding a photo to an album does not update the modified time

Comment: There is 'modified_major' field on the album table which is described as major changes to an album such as photo additions happen. I tried adding photos to an existing album and see no change in time. Sample call: [link]https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20aid,%20modified_major%20from%20album%20where%20owner%20=%20me%28%29%20and%20visible%20=%20%27EVERYONE%27 [link] and Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album/